# App init fails the first time, but successes the second time

Tags: windows, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm having an issue with worklight init in windows build. 
The first time it is called, it is failing till timeout, but the second time, is succeeds without any issue. any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Client Logs:

> ondeviceready event dispatched
>
> wlclient init started
>
> CookieMgr read cookies: {}
>
> before: initOptions.onSuccess
>
> Request [/apps/services/api/.../windowsphone8/init]
>
> after: initOptions.onSuccess
>
> added onPause and onResume event handlers
>
> Request [/apps/services/api/.../windowsphone8/init]
>
> Application is now  online.
>
> response [/apps/services/api/.../windowsphone8/init] success:
>   /*-secure-
>
> {"userPrefs":{},"WL-Authentication-Success":{"wl_directUpdateRealm":{"userId":"null","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"null","deviceId":"null"},"wl_remoteDisableRealm":{"userId":"null","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"null","deviceId":"null"},"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"userId":"47u3k5h5bh7vkam0nbgqkhmnfd","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"47u3k5h5bh7vkam0nbgqkhmnfd","deviceId":"...."},"wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm":{"userId":"eEMg454f+/EF1RhvvAr/bl+Le7miVqMXIeKuglII9VA=","attributes":{"mobileClientData":"com.worklight.core.auth.ext.MobileClientData@d3af5afd"},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"eEMg454f+/EF1RhvvAr/bl+Le7miVqMXIeKuglII9VA=","deviceId":"...."},"wl_anonymousUserRealm":{"userId":"...","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"...","deviceId":"..."}},"gadgetProps":{"ENVIRONMENT":"windowsphone8"},"userInfo":{"SubscribeServlet":{"userId":null,"attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":0,"displayName":null,"deviceId":null},"wl_directUpdateRealm":{"userId":"null","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"null","deviceId":"null"},"SingleStepAuthRealm":{"userId":null,"attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":0,"displayName":null,"deviceId":null},"wl_authenticityRealm":{"userId":null,"attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":0,"displayName":null,"deviceId":null},"SampleAppRealm":{"userId":null,"attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":0,"displayName":null,"deviceId":null},"wl_remoteDisableRealm":{"userId":"null","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"null","deviceId":"null"},"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"userId":"...","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"...","deviceId":"..."},"wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm":{"userId":null,"attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":0,"displayName":null,"deviceId":null},"wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm":{"userId":"...","attributes":{"mobileClientData":"com.worklight.core.auth.ext.MobileClientData@d3af5afd"},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"eEMg454f+/EF1RhvvAr/bl+Le7miVqMXIeKuglII9VA=","deviceId":"eEMg454f+/EF1RhvvAr/bl+Le7miVqMXIeKuglII9VA="},"myserver":{"userId":"...","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"6cad1d09-5770-4090-9f21-057841e16eb3","deviceId":"..."},"wl_anonymousUserRealm":{"userId":"...","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"...","deviceId":"....."}}}*/
>
> wlclient connect success
>
> Request [/apps/services/loguploader]
>
> Request [/apps/services/loguploader]
>
> Application is now  online.
>
> response [/apps/services/loguploader] success:
>
> Application is now  online.
>
> response [/apps/services/loguploader] success:
>
> Piggybacking event transmission
>
> Flush called

Comment: Will be useful if you'll add server logs, client logs, wireshark logs...

Comment: The client logs look proper to me. Where and when do you see this issue with "first time fail"?

Comment: @VivinK : Actually we are always getting the response on second init call only and also it takes some time

Comment: You will need to explain a little more than that. By two init calls are you referring these two calls in sucession?
---------------
Request [/apps/services/api/.../windowsphone8/init]

after: initOptions.onSuccess

added onPause and onResume event handlers

Request [/apps/services/api/.../windowsphone8/init]
----------------

or are you talking about two tries?